# Insert Divs before and after element using javascript Or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs,the first one is hidden and second one is visible:

```
<div id="first" style="display:none;">
  //First 
</div>

<div id="second">
  <button onclick="javascript:show()" > Copy </button>
</div>
```

I want to add a copy of the first div before and after the second div when a user clicks the copy button.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? Perhaps show us what the initial markup should be, and also what the resulting markup should be? Please note that cloning the first `DIV` will result in multiple elements having the same `Id`.

Comment: look i have two divs one div is hidden and other is visible . In the div which is visible i have a button , i want that when user click on that button a javascript function get copy the hidden div and paste it before and after the visible div . Hope you got it

Comment: That kind of snippy attitude gets you nowhere.

Comment: visible or not (the copied ones)?

Comment: @Ahsan Attari you don't 'paste' in HTML you 'insert' you don't deal with text but with nodes.

Comment: I edited the question description, learn it remember it and next time write it like I did and without any attitude.

Answer (score 2):

you should remove the `onclick` on the button and add

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    $("#second").before($("#first").clone(true,true).attr("id", "firstBeforeCopy").show()); // clone first before second
    $("#second").after($("#first").clone(true,true).attr("id", "firstAfterCopy").show());   // clone first after second
});
```

mind the `clone(true, true)` which also clone's already binded events

Comment: You would have 3 divs with the same id that way...

Comment: good point changing it right now

Comment: Regrading your "side note", the `prop` for `attr` thing was fixed back in jQuery 1.6.

Comment: @Sparky672 sorry that's dutch for doh or ohoh :)

Comment: Oh I see.  LOL.  You're going to fix your answer then?

Answer (score 1):

```
function show(){
  var a = '<div class="firstCopy">' + $('#first').html() + '</div>'
  $('#second').before(a)
  $('#second').after(a)
}
```

That should be it ;)

Comment: If it's done then set his answer to approved.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work for you?

```
$('#second').before($('#first').clone());
$('#second').after($('#first').clone());
```